# R: Looping over vector of strings for function input

Tags: r, function

I have a vector of inputs in R and a function `f`.

`inputs <- c('input1','input2','input3',...,'input10')`

I want to obtain `output <- c(f(input1),f(input2),...,f(input10))` without writing this out.

How can I do this in an efficient manner, and without using a `for` loop? Also, I'd like to do this without referring to the subscript on input (I just numbered it for the sake of this question).

Further, `f('input1')` does not work while `f(input1)` does. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope `Vectorize` could help

```
Vectorize(f)(inputs)
```

Comment: I still seem to run into the issue of "f('input1') does not work while f(input1) does." How can I fix 'inputs'?

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out: using mgets(inputs).

Comment: @FakeAnalyst56 Yes, you got it. you need `mget`, then try `sapply(mget(inuts),f)`